# When should "&" be used on both sides of an assignment?

Tags: pointers, rust, dereference, borrow-checker, borrowing

The [`Condvar`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) docs shows an example that includes the following:

```
let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
// <snipped for brevity>
let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = &*pair;
```

I'm wondering what the advantage might be to including `&` on both sides of this assignment. In other words, why not just write:

```
let (ref lock, ref cvar) = *pair;
```

Both versions compile; is there any semantic difference? And if not, is there any reason to prefer the syntax that appears in the example?

In general, **I'm still struggling to understand when/where `&*` should idiomatically appear in Rust code**. My instinct is to "see" (read) this character combination as a no-op, though I understand that because of Rust's `Deref` semantics this isn't the case.

Comment: Let me add that I've found https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0241-deref-conversions.md most helpful in understanding the design intention/thinking behind Deref behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `&` in this case does not make difference because the LHS is a [destructuring pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#destructuring). In my opinion, this example should not use `&`. However, in other cases there is a important difference: `*` moves the deferred value:

```
let p = *pair; // *Deref::deref(pair)
// pair cannot be used anymore because the deferred value was moved

let p = &*pair; // &*Deref::deref(pair)
// p: &(Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new())
// p and pair can be used
```

> I'm still struggling to understand when/where &* should idiomatically appear in Rust code.

In general, use `&*` when a reference to the deferred value is needed, like in a function call:

```
fn sum(a: &u32, b: &u32) -> u32 {
   a + b
}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(10);
    // println!("{:?}", sum(&1, x)); // do not work x is Box<u32>
    // println!("{:?}", sum(&1, *x)); // do not work *x is u32
    println!("{:?}", sum(&1, &*x)); // ok &*x is &u32
}
```

> My instinct is to "see" (read) this character combination as a no-op, though I understand that because of Rust's Deref semantics this isn't the case.

Considering that [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/deref-coercions.html) says "`Deref` is useful for writing custom pointer types", I like to read `&*` as "a reference to the value that this (smart) pointer points at".

Comment: This is great! Can you clarify for `// *Deref::deref(pair)` why the `*` *and* `Deref` both appear in your explanation? Shouldn't just one be there?

Comment: The compiler translates `*pair` to `*Deref::deref(pair)` and `&*pair` to `&*Deref::deref(pair)`, considering that `Deref::deref` returns `&T`, then `*pair` produces `T` and `&*pair` produces `&T`.

Comment: Silly question, but if `*pair` expands to `*Deref::deref(pair)`, then why doesn't this in turn expand to `*Deref::refer(*Deref::deref(pair))`?

Comment: Also is it at all possible to explain https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/up/src/liballoc/boxed.rs.html#459 — how is this not recursive?

Comment: I tried to find an official description of how the translation is done but did not succeed. But I suppose that the expansion is done one time for each `*` and that the result is not expanded again. If I find an official description, I will update the answer.